# Why did Merlin lose his powers and not Nimue?

Tags: the-crystal-cave

In Mary Stewart’s  *The Crystal Cave* series, Merlin always professes a deep fear of having intimate relations lest he lose his powers. In the third book, however, he eventually loses his virginity to Nimue, who is also his protégé.

How is it that she can lose her virginity and retain her powers, going from strength to strength as a witch while Merlin loses everything?